# unexpected EOF with fmt.Scanner

Tags: string, go, token, eof

If I want to scan through a string, I can do this:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   r := strings.NewReader("west north east")
   for {
      var s string
      _, e := fmt.Fscan(r, &s)
      fmt.Printf("%q %v\n", s, e)
      if e != nil { break }
   }
}
```

Result:

```
"west" <nil>
"north" <nil>
"east" <nil>
"" EOF
```

I recently discovered `fmt.Scanner` [1], so I thought I would try to implement
it. I came up with this:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

type comma struct { tok string }

func (c *comma) Scan(state fmt.ScanState, verb rune) error {
   tok, err := state.Token(false, func(r rune) bool {
      return r != ','
   })
   if err != nil {
      return err
   }
   if _, _, err := state.ReadRune(); err != nil {
      if len(tok) == 0 {
         return err
      }
   }
   c.tok = string(tok)
   return nil
}

func main() {
   r := strings.NewReader("west,north,east")
   for {
      var c comma
      _, e := fmt.Fscan(r, &c)
      fmt.Printf("%q %v\n", c.tok, e)
      if e != nil { break }
   }
}
```

Result:

```
"west" <nil>
"north" <nil>
"east" <nil>
"" unexpected EOF
```

So the result is pretty close, but what bothers me is the `unexpected EOF`. Is
it possible to just get a regular `EOF` with a custom `fmt.Scanner`? Am I doing
something wrong here, or is this a bug?

1. https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Scanner

Comment: I don't think it is possible in the current version of Go. See: https://golang.org/src/fmt/scan.go?s=2653:2699#L961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ian Lance Taylor on the `golang-nuts` list, he suggested to `panic`
the error instead of `return`. In the Go code, `Fscan` calls a function
`doScan`, which in turn calls a function `errorHandler` [1]. This last function
uses `recover` to turn any `panic` into regular error. This program gives
idential output to my original example:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

type comma struct { tok string }

func (c *comma) Scan(state fmt.ScanState, verb rune) error {
   tok, err := state.Token(false, func(r rune) bool {
      return r != ','
   })
   if err != nil { return err }
   if _, _, err := state.ReadRune(); err != nil {
      if len(tok) == 0 {
         panic(err)
      }
   }
   c.tok = string(tok)
   return nil
}

func main() {
   r := strings.NewReader("west,north,east")
   for {
      var c comma
      _, err := fmt.Fscan(r, &c)
      fmt.Printf("%q %v\n", c.tok, err)
      if err != nil { break }
   }
}
```

1. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.4/src/fmt/scan.go#L1056-L1067